# How to show pervious and future steps on Onepage Checkout?

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout

In onepage.phtml the line hides the step options:

```
<div id="checkout-step-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
```

And upon returning from the controller, it sets the completed step to display:none

I've dug in, and cannot find the code that sets this display to none. I would like to customize this, showing the user what they have entered and possibly animating the display instead of the bulky loading from step to step.

Any help on where to start looking where this code is?

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens like this.

All the steps are defaulted to being closed in the phtml file as shown by your snippet.

```
<div id="checkout-step-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
```

Then the checkout accordion will open the currently active step with the following function call.

```
accordion.openSection('opc-<?php echo $this->getActiveStep() ?>');
```

This option section will find the appropriate section and then show it via js.

```
var contents = Element.select(section, '.a-item');
contents[0].show();
```